# URL Redirect with Plus Sign

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I am updating the naming conventions on some old urls. I am using htaccess to redirect to the new urls.

I have some urls that use plus signs and these do not seem to want to redirect. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)-C++-Programming-Tutorial-C++-Seminar\.htm$ http://www.domain.com$1-C++-Training-Course.htm
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `+` symbols with a backslash; they are interpreted as part of the regex and indicate that the preceding character should appear one-or-more times.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)-C\+\+-Programming-Tutorial-C\+\+-Seminar\.htm$ http://www.domain.com$1-C++-Training-Course.htm
```

Comment: The addition of the backslash does not seem to be working. The link is still not redirecting.

Comment: I need that because I have hundreds of urls that have a slightly different beginning part, but all the last part is the same(the part with the + signs)

Comment: It works for me. Did you reload the server after changing the configuration? Do you have any other rules that are matching before this one (and taking precedence)? Take a look at your access log & error log.

Comment: no, I did not reload. I will give that shot in the morning when there is less traffic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: An Apache "reload" doesn't kill existing connections, only a "restart" does. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/stopping.html#graceful - it should be safe to reload without interrupting your users.